# How to mention a paper with multiple authors on the CV?

Tags: publications, cv

I am part of a paper with multiple authors (16). My name is unfortunately the last one. How do I mention this one my CV?

Comment: I usually have something like Author1, Author2, .... Me [5th of 10] ... AuthorLast, title etc

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll follow the same.

Comment: Are you in an "order by contribution" or in an "order by alphabet" field?

Comment: Order by alphabet!

Comment: In order by alphabet areas, I have sometimes seen people omit their own names and show the author list as "With X, Y, Z", but I am not sure if it would be appropriate for a CV.

Comment: The comment by @GoodDeeds matches what I do on my CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP said in the comments that their field uses alphabetical ordering of authors names, there are 2 reasonable options:

1. List authors names in alphabetical order, i.e., as published (as in Buffy's answer).  If desired, you can highlight your name using bold or the like.
2. After the title of each paper, write something like "(with Author 1, Author 2, ... and Author n-1)" for joint papers.  This is what I do, mainly so my name doesn't appear on every other line of my CV, but I also wouldn't do this if it wasn't a reasonably common approach in my field.

That said, you should be consistent and list each publication the same way, and also look at CVs of some people in your area to make sure your formatting isn't out of place.

Answer (score 2):

Just list the paper the way it was published (assuming all authors are named). As long as your name appears anywhere it will be obvious to people in your field what the implication is. You don't need to mark "yourself" in any way.

For a paper with hundreds/thousands of authors, such as can be done at CERN, for example, you would need a different mechanism, probably a note that you were one of the "et. al." authors.

---

There are a few papers for which the listing of the authors is longer than the paper itself. Google can easily find a few.

Comment: So are you saying to list all the authors?

Comment: That would be best. It would also emphasize that the listing is alphabetical. It also emphasizes that you are a collaborator, which in academia is a good thing.

Comment: @Aymuos Alternatively, just cite it in a regular way - there is no hard rule that your name should explicitly appear in that list. I'd say I've seen regular citations the most often in "formal" CVs where a certain template had to be followed (or, if the author list isn't too long, the full listing like Buffy suggested); in a more free format ("describe select results over past 5 years") "With X, Y, Z" could also be observed. IMO the CV itself should be relatively brief and all the details go to the addendums or provided per request during an interview.